# Where to store encryption key using node.js?

Tags: encryption, key, secret-key

I have been doing a lot of research but I can't understand where I should save the encryption key in a production environment?

In local environment I have a .env file, but it feels very risky to have the encryption key written there in plain text in a production environment. I could encrypt it but then I just have another key to save somewhere.

I am not using AWS or any other big cloud platform, so I can't use AWS KMS etc.

I have looked into alternatives to AWS KMS, such as Doppler (doppler.com). You can store the key there, but to get the key with their API they use tokens to authenticate the requests, so then I have to store the token somewhere safe.. so it feels like I just running a rat race.

So I really need help here. Where should I store the encryption key? Where would you (and where can you) store it if you were not using any big cloud platform?